# Choose install location Steam games on Mac

Tags: steam, macos

I'm pretty sure I have set it up at home on my iMac, but I can't for the life of me find out how to set it up again on my Macbook Air. I have recently purchased a USB-stick to run Steam off of, because Steam was hogging GBs on my internal SSD. However, I can't see the function where I can change the install location.

I am already running Steam from the USB-stick, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I don't run OS X, but on windows and linux - you can add a library under settings -> downloads -> steam library folders, or just add it when you install the game.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Weird they call it a library, as that is something way more OS-like than it is program-like (at least on OS X). Well, if you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply add it as a library under settings/downloads - this is universal to all  variations of Steam.

[image]

Comment: Does that even work for removable media?

Comment: @Powerlord Yes it does :) 64GB leave-in USB 3.0 stick, perfect for games!

Comment: How do you download to it? I'm sorry, but I don't know how to use steam that well.

Comment: You quite literally add the library folder, and pick that folder while dile downloading.